# Dynamic Programming solution for finding shortest distance to travel between points

Tags: dynamic-programming, recursion

So consider a person located at point $c$ (let's say $c=140$). Given a set of other points, for example, $P = \{100, 50, 190\}$. The cost of traveling to a point $P_i$ is then $|c-P_i|$. Points can be traversed in any order, so let's do them in the order of the example set.

This leads us having to travel the distance $40+50+140 = 230$. A better option would have been to travel the order of $\{190, 100, 50\}$ which gives the distance $50+90+50 = 190$.

I want to try to set up a dynamic programming solution to this problem. I realize that at each step I have to consider the option of traveling to *all* available points (i.e discover all possible paths, and comparing them all to find the shortest one)

First things first I'd want to set up a recursive formula for the problem, but I can't seem to find out how... I feel like once I have a recursive formula the rest should work itself out.

Comment: Intuitively, the solution is to go to the closest extremal point, and then traverse the rest in order.

Comment: Yeah I figured as much, but I'm more interested in the solution wherein a recursive formula can be applied to an unsorted set

Comment: Sometimes dynamic programming just isn't the right technique.

Comment: That is true, and I realize that, however out of interest I would still want to apply dynamic programming techniques to solve this problem

Comment: You'll have to store the shortest path visiting a certain set of points and ending at a specific point. The algorithm will run in exponential time.

Comment: Dynamic programming is TTBOMK *the best* technique for this problem, as @YuvalFilmus's last comment suggests :)  But only if you have enough memory.

Comment: So @j_random_hacker how would I set up the problem? I realize the problem I'm solving but phrasing it order of a useful data-structure (I'm assuming some kind of 2D array for memoization?) isn't as obvious to me

Comment: Try adapting the [Held-Karp algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Held%E2%80%93Karp_algorithm) for TSP to your problem.

Comment: @j_random_hacker Thanks! This seems to be what I need